# Google Analytics - _trackSocial event

Tags: google-analytics

I am not sure whether my code is incorrect or if I am not looking at the right place on the GA dashboard.

I have included the GA script in the head section.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', '<%= Settings.google_id%>', 'healthfundit.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

On page load I am setting the account (don't know if this is needed):

```
$(function(){
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%= Settings.google_id%>']);
  });
```

And I am calling the _gaq.push when a Tweet action is fired (from debugging, I know this line of code is getting executed):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial','Twitter', 'Tweet', '', '']);
```

But I can't find the info about this tweet anywhere on the GA dashboard.

**UPDATE**
I have changed the code to:

```
ga('send', 'social', 'Twitter', 'Checkout Tweet', 'healthfundit.com', 
{'hitCallback': function(){alert('analytics.js done sending data');}});
```

And after tweeting, the callback function is getting called and displaying the alert message. But I just don't see anything on the GA dashboard about this event.

**2nd UPDATE**
Like Blexy said in comment below, to see the info in GA you have to go to *Acquisition > Plugins and select the Social Source and Action as your Primary Dimension*.
And this is very important: The info does not appear on the dashboard instantly. It seems to take about a day for the info to appear in GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use the [old (ga.js) social tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial) with the new [Universal Analytics (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) base code.

Try using the [Universal Analytics social interaction tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions) instead:

```
ga('send', 'social', 'Twitter', 'Tweet', 'http://targeturl.com');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Blexy for that. I have changed the code. I still don't see the events anywhere on the GA dashboard.

Comment: I don't believe social events are available within Real-time reports, so you'll have to go to Acquisition > Plugins and select the Social Source and Action as your Primary Dimension. You should start seeing data propagate shortly.

Comment: Thank you. I see them now. Seems it takes about a day for the info to appear in GA.